# regex match with perl with quotation marks

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading in a file and I want to find a timestamp value and replace it with 0's before outputting it to another file. So I am trying to search and replace this value TIME="20180731.5622743"
for something like this in a file
TIME="00000000.0000000"

So far i've got..

```
open(INPUT, $path) or die $!;
open(OUTPUT, ">$susex_path")  or die $!;

while(<INPUT>){
   $line =~ s/([0-9]+8.[0-9]+7)/000000.0000000/g;
   print OUTPUT $line;
   }
}
close(INPUT);    
close(OUTPUT);
```

The search and replace only partially works as the line contains other timestamps that I don't want to replace. If I include the full bit to search and replace the quotation marks appear to be preventing a successful search and replace.. e.g(

```
$line =~ s/TIME=\"([0-9]+8.[0-9]+7)\"/TIME=\"00000000.0000000\"/g
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `[0-9]+8` does not mean 8 digits but 1 or more digits followed by 8. you want `[0-9]{8}`

Comment: There's nothing special about `"`. You don't even need to escape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<=TIME=")\d{8}\.\d{7}(?=")`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BbI6KC/1)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Note that \d will match more than [0-9] as it matches any decimal number which as of Unicode version 9.0 is 580 characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this which may be quicker

```
$line =~ s/TIME="[0-9]{8}\.[0-9]{7}"/TIME="00000000.0000000"/g
```

Note as mentioned in the comments to your question you need {8} and {7} not +8 and +7 also `"` is not special in either side of `s///`.

However `.` is special and needs escaping; also you don't need `( ... )` unless you want to use the original time stamp outside the regex